# How to handle error when using browser notifications?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, push-notification

I have Vue JS application where I should create browser notification for users when they get notification.

I created notification for testing purposes.
Notification is run on mounted hook of the application
Notification is shown successfully on screen, but I have an error in console:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'showNotification' of undefined

**Why do I get this error even if my notification is successfully shown?**

**How can I handle it?**

```
mounted () {
    this.checkUserNotificationPermission()
  },

checkUserNotificationPermission () {
      if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
        this.displayBrowserNotification()
      } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
          if (permission === 'granted') {
            this.displayBrowserNotification()
          }
        })
      }
    }

displayBrowserNotification () {
      const title = 'New Message'
      const options = {
        body: 'Body description',
        icon: 'path/to/icon',
        vibrate: [100, 50, 100]
      }
      const notification = new Notification(title, options)
      navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then((reg) => {
        reg.showNotification(notification)
      })
    }
```

Comment: The [API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/getRegistration#return_value) indicate it possibly resolves to `undefined`, and their example also has a null-check of the result, so you should probably do the same in your code.

Comment: Thanks@tony19 I checked if registration exists in if condition, not it is working and the error is gone

Answer (score 0):

I should check if registration exists:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then((reg) => {
        if (reg) {
          reg.showNotification(notification)
        }
      })
```

Now the error is gone